# Yii Framework Unknown Property Exception

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, yii-components

I know this might seem trivial but I really can't figure it out. I'm starting to develop a database application using Yii Framework and MySQL. I tried following the simple basic tutorial : 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html
, but I used my own table "Supermarkets".
I'm getting this error:

Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\Supermarkets::name

It's obvious that the method get ('name') is causing this error, but I don't know how to fix this.

This is my code:

...models/supermarkets.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Supermarkets extends ActiveRecord
{



}
```

...controllers/SupermarketsController.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Supermarkets;

class SupermarketsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Supermarkets::find();

        $pagination = new Pagination([
            'defaultPageSize' => 5,
            'totalCount' => $query->count(),
        ]);

        $supermarkets = $query->orderBy('name')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'supermarkets' => $supermarkets,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
    }
}
```

...views/Supermarkets/index.php:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<h1>Supermarkets</h1>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($supermarkets as $supermarket): ?>
    <li>
        <?= $supermarket->name?>
        <?= $supermarket->location ?>
        <?= $supermarket->telephone ?>
        <?= $supermarket->fax ?>
        <?= $supermarket->website ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

Supermarkets.db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supermarkets` (
  `Name` varchar(71) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(68) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(29) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Website` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: could you add the column titles for the table for `Supermarkets`?

Comment: Could you show db table that correspond to Supermarkets entity?

Comment: I edited my question and added the code for the sql table.

Comment: Variables in PHP are case sensitive. Try changing all occurrences of `name` to `Name` in your PHP code and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you lose in model `Supermarkets`:

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'Supermarkets';
    }
```

If you not set method, default table-name will be `supermarkets`. Because in `yii\db\ActiveRecord` set:

```
public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%' . Inflector::camel2id(StringHelper::basename(get_called_class()), '_') . '}}';
    }
```

EDIT

Use delete this from your model

```
 /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'Supermarkets';
        }
```

And use

```
<?= $supermarket->Name?>
        <?= $supermarket->Location ?>
        <?= $supermarket->Telephone ?>
        <?= $supermarket->Fax ?>
        <?= $supermarket->Website ?>
```

Or better way. Use your first code. And change columns -> set small first letter. Like that

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supermarkets` (
  `name` varchar(71) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(68) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(29) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this code to my supermarkets.php, but I'm still getting the error.